# Unity Rotate Foor using Input.acceleration

Tags: android, rotation, unity-game-engine, tilt-sensor

I am trying to rotate floor using Input.acceleration. I want to rotate floor around the point where player is standing and  to limit my rotations at certain angles also stop at 0 if Input.acceleration is close to zero. considering that i'm newbie at game programming I've came up with this code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Tilt : MonoBehaviour {

    public float maxRotationAngle = 350;                    // max rotation right
    public float minRotationAngle = 10;                     // max rotation left 
    public float rotationSpeed = 20;                        //rotation speed
    public Transform rotateAround;                          //rotation point
    private bool stopRotation = false;                      //if this is true rotation stops
    private int stopDir;                                    //direction where rotation stops -1 equals left 0 center 1 right

    void Update () {

        int tiltDir = 0;                                    //input tilt direction
        float accel = Input.acceleration.x;                 //input tilt value
        float currentRotation = transform.eulerAngles.z;    //current rotation

        //set rotation direction
        if (accel > 0) {
            tiltDir = 1;
        }else if (accel < 0){
            tiltDir = -1;
        }

        //stop rotation left
        if (!stopRotation && (currentRotation < maxRotationAngle && currentRotation > 270)) {
            stopRotation = true;
            stopDir = -1;
        }
        //stop rotation right
        if (!stopRotation && (currentRotation > minRotationAngle && currentRotation < 270)) {
            stopRotation = true;
            stopDir = 1;
        }
        //allow rotation right
        if (stopRotation && stopDir < 0 && Input.acceleration.x > 0) {
            stopRotation = false;

        }
        //allow rotation left
        if (stopRotation && stopDir > 0 && Input.acceleration.x < 0) {
            stopRotation = false;
        }
        //stop rotation center
        if(!stopRotation  && currentRotation < 0.2 || (currentRotation > 359.8 && currentRotation < 360)){
            if(accel > -0.1 && accel < 0.1){
                stopRotation = true;
                stopDir = 0;
            }
        }
        //allow rotation from center
        if(stopRotation && stopDir == 0 && (accel < -0.1 || accel > 0.1)){
            stopRotation = false;
        }
        //apply rotation
        if(!stopRotation){
            transform.RotateAround(rotateAround.position, new Vector3(0, 0, tiltDir), rotationSpeed * Mathf.Abs(accel) * Time.deltaTime);
        }

    }
}
```

This is working but this approach is not exact and i think there are cheaper ways of doing this. So Is there a better way?

Comment: Do you really need to rotate the floor, wouldn't it be easier to rotate the player itself?

Comment: No because I want physics objects to interact with the floor depending of its rotation.

Comment: Why is minRotationAngle greater than 0? Would it not make more sense to have minRotationAngle and maxRotationAngle be between -180 and 180 degrees? So in this case -170 and 170 respectively?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this, which I think accomplishes what you wanted, although I may have misread your code. I've removed your magic number, changed the angles to map between -180 and 180 and renamed your variables to have full names for better maintainability.

```
public float maxRotationAngle = 170;
public float minRotationAngle = -170;
public float minimumAcceleration = 0.1f;
public float rotationSpeed = 20;
public Transform rotateAroundTransform;

void Update () 
{
    float deltaAcceleration = Mathf.Abs(Input.acceleration.x);
    float currentRotation = transform.eulerAngles.z;

    //stop rotation outside of angle range and motion range
    if (currentRotation > minRotationAngle && 
        currentRotation < maxRotationAngle && 
        deltaAcceleration < minimumAcceleration) 
    {
        //set rotation direction
        int tiltDirection = Input.acceleration.x > 0 ? 1 : -1;
        transform.RotateAround(rotateAroundTransform.position, new Vector3(0, 0, tiltDirection), rotationSpeed * deltaAcceleration * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm glad it helped! Please mark this answer as correct using the tick under the vote buttons. Thanks.

Comment: I can't. I have not enough reputation sorry.

Comment: Hi, actually you don't need any reputation at all to mark an answer! Look here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Glad to have been of help :)